# Using PythonSDK for Azure to provision servicebus resources

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I want to use Azure Python SDK to provision ServiceBus queue.
I am able to find one package https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/ but it seems to be taking queue name as input.
can you please guide me how I can provision Azure service bus queue using python SDK

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The package you would want to use is [`azure-mgmt-servicebus`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-servicebus/). The method you would need to use for creating a queue is [`create_or_update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.queuesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--namespace-name--queue-name--parameters----kwargs-).